# Conversion Errror when trying to insert DateTimeOffset into SQL table

Tags: sql, asp.net, fluent-migrator

I am trying to insert a datetimeoffset value in SQL2014 using fluentmigrator but the query itself also fails in query manager. Any idea on how I should insert this?

```
Field - CreatedDate - DateTimeOffset(7)
```

Sending the value as a datetime works fine e.g. 2018/02/28 12:19:25

Adding the T marker or datetimeoffset causes the error
"Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string"

So both of these attempts fail

```
28/02/2018 12:42:37 +00:00
28/02/2018T12:42:37 +00:00
```

Here is a cut down version of the fluent code that fails

```
 Insert.IntoTable("Tenant")
         .Row(new 
                {
                    TenantID = Tenant1GUID,
                    TenantName = "MyName",
                    CreatedDate = DateTimeOffset.Now,
                });
```

Here is a cut down version of the fluent code that works

```
 Insert.IntoTable("Tenant")
         .Row(new 
                {
                    TenantName = "MyName",
                    CreatedDate = DateTime.Now,
                });
```

SQL Code that fails

```
 INSERT INTO [dbo].[Tenant] ([TenantName], [CreatedDate]) 
    VALUES ('Demo', '2018/02/28T12:19:25 +05:00:00')
```

SQL Code that works

```
 INSERT INTO [dbo].[Tenant] ([TenantName], [CreatedDate]) 
    VALUES ('Demo', '2018/02/28 12:19:25')
```

Comment: I think your timezone part shouldn't contain the last `:00` - I can convert `'2018/02/28 12:19:25 +05:00'` to a datetimeoffset(7)

Answer (score 0):

Iam not sure what exact error you getting but make sure the table column type should be set to datetimeoffset.